# Get an input from user scanner class

Tags: java

normally when I get a user interaction from a keyboard I use class scanner to do so but the problem I noticed when using its methods is that it's not handling exception!  For example

```
Scanner input = new scanner();
Int number = input.nextInt();
```

The above works good for all integer numbers but if the user mistakly entered a character or a string, it will throw an exception and stops executing the rest of the program.

My question is there any way to avoid this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to catch the exception. Or use the [`hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) method to prevent the exception from being thrown in the first place.

```
try {
    int number = input.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("That wasn't a number!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should catch the exception and ask the user again?

See http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson14.htm for exactly your problem.